# Json Array Size and Slice Function TypeScript

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular2-services

I am trying to implement pagination for my datatable by using typescript and angular2. I have json array, and i need to slice and get length of the array for pagination purpose. However, i am stucked with this case. I got error as **this.data.slice is not a function** and  i couldn't get the lenght of my array as well.

```
 Json Array : [{ "id" : "2", "city" : "Test" , "country" :"TestCountry" },
  {"id" : "1", "city" : "Test1" , "country" :"TestCountry1" }]
```

and code snippets that i wrote as below :

```
  // get pager object from service
      this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.data.length, page);
    // get current page of items
    this.pagedItems = this.data.slice(this.pager.startIndex,       this.pager.endIndex + 1);
```

this.data represents my json array in this case. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If both `length` and `slice` are not available, your data array is likely not initialized. Please provide more details of your array instantiation.